# SimPy - Simulation Clock

Tags: python, simpy

Is there a way to reset (set to ZERO) the simulation clock using simPy?

Today I am reseting the while Environment using

```
env = simpy.Environment()
```

It works, but it seems a huge workaround to a simple issue.

Comment: why do you need to do this? what are you trying to do?

Comment: I teach Simulation at University, this will allow me to show different situations to my students, just changing bits and pieces of the code, without running the whole code over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is, and I would think doing so could mess up the event queue.

I would think you would want to use

```
env = simpy.Environment()
```

to make sure your are starting with a clean environment with no left over events or resources.